# What tool to use to draw this graph?

Tags: soft-question

[image]

I used to use Microsoft Word to draw this type of graphs, but it is not so convenient and it is difficult to be precise and accurate in details. Is there any better tool?

Comment: If the drawing is qualitative i like to use [inkscape](https://inkscape.org/), if it is quantitative i like to use the python library [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/stable/index.html).

Comment: GeoGebra will do it. You can export the graphic in several formats. I use Geogebra for all my graphs and diagrams.

Comment: Desmos can do it too. https://www.desmos.com/calculator